# Find the hidden word!

Tags: word, cipher, letters

What word is hidden here?

> IVxVII IIxVIII IIIxII IIIxII IIxIII IVxVII IVxVII

Hint 1:

> x = *

Hint 2:

> [image]

Hint 3:

> _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Hint 4:

> AMOUNTxKEY

Hint 5 (last one):

> [image]

Comment: I think you should probably have given the hints out an order of magnitude slower...

Comment: I seriously think that the last two hints gave it all away. There was no need of the first three.

Comment: I largely agree.  The first three hints said almost nothing, the fourth was enough to give it away immediately in my case, and the fifth was more a solution than a hint. (But I have much sympathy: giving good hints is really really difficult.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De-Romanizing gives 4x7,2x8,3x2,3x2,2x3,4x7,4x7.

As indicated by the last hint [EDITED to add: when I wrote this, the last hint was number 4], this is a

> mobile-phone-keyboard cipher where *m*x*n* means you press the key numbered *n* a total of *m* times

which as *hexomino* says leads to the answer

> SUCCESS.

Comment: Well done :) :)

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. +1

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> Success

Reasoning

> I have no idea how the Roman numerals link to the letters but the word follows the pattern ABCCDAA and there are very few words which follow that pattern (one other one I found was "falloff").
>  Very cheap, I know. I'll try to figure out the reasoning.

Comment: +1 for the right word, now figure out the reasoning for a correct answer :)

Comment: Check Hint 4 :)